# Sorry, there was an error uploading your file

Tags: php, file, upload

I am uploading file in php and gettng following error.

Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    print($target_file);
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: use **print_r($_FILES);** for debugging purpose, Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908700/how-to-debug-move-uploaded-file-in-php

Comment: Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => origdata_c.n..xlsx [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: Try to increase upload_max_filesize in php.ini , restart server and check.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r($_FILES)` in order to debug the problem.

Your output was:

> Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => origdata_c.n..xlsx [type]
>   => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

According to the Manual, a value of 1 for the error key means:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE (value 1)
>
> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Therefore, the solution should be to increase the `upload_max_filesize` configuration in your php.ini.

Comment: I just checked
upload_max_filesize = 100M while file upload size is only 3.1 M only

Comment: @mandata  you need to increase `post_max_size`,`upload_max_filesize` both in `php.ini`

Comment: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are both 100 M while i am uploading 3.1 M file still gettting same error

Comment: Maybe this configuration is being overwritten or ignored? Do you have other php.ini files? Is it on a shared server? Can you please run **phpinfo()** and check the value of those variables?

Comment: Create a new php file and write "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" and share the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        print($target_file)."<br>";
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

print_r($_FILES);

Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => prices.xlsx [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet [tmp_name] => /tmp/phppLSmjf [error] => 0 [size] => 1527924 ) ) Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

$target_dir = "temp/";// Then grant rights to write on this folder.

This solved my issue

Comment: Please explain your code.